# problems initializing a local variable in function

Tags: c++

Every time i run the code below i get the same result which is an error that states that "diameter" is an uninitialized local variable. What i need is for the input entered in the getDiam() function to be initialized to diameter.
There have been a couple ways i have already tried to do this another way including:

```
double getDiam()
{
double diameter;
double input;
cout << "Please enter the diameter of your floor: ";
cin >> input;
diameter = input;
return diameter;
}
```

This ^^ did not work.

```
//prototypes
double getDiam();
double calcSqFeet(double);
const double PI = 3.14;

int main()
{
double diameter, 
       squareFeet;

getDiam();
calcSqFeet(diameter);

}
double getDiam()
{
double diameter = 0;
cout << "Please enter the diameter of your floor: ";
cin >> diameter;
return diameter;
}

double calcSqFeet(double diameter)
{
double radius = diameter / 2;
double squareFeet = PI * radius * radius;
return squareFeet;
}
```

Comment: Please extract a minimal example, your question is off-topic without it. That said, variables named `diameter` declared in different functions are different objects. Even variables in the same function when it is called twice are different objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `diameter` being passed to `calcSqFeet` is not the same `diameter` that is being taken input.
Your return value from `getDiam` is not used in `main`.

You should change the `getDiam` call in `main` to `diameter=getDiam();`.

Answer (score -1):

If you read the warning message (I doubt it's an error unless you enabled a "warnings as error" option) you will see that it's not about the use of `diameter` in the `getDiam` function. It's in the `main` function where you indeed use an equally named variable `diameter` in the call to `calcSqfeet` without initialization.

The thing you're missing is assigning the result of `getDiam` to the `diameter` variable in the `main` function.

Lesson to be learned: Always actually *read* the error or warning messages the compiler gives you. Including line-numbers and potential function names. to help you locate the actual location of the error/warning.

Second lesson to be learned: Local variables in a function are actually local to just that function. Two variables with the same name but in different functions are still two different variables without any connection to each other.